# What ports should I open to use EC2 as a nameserver

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, bind

I have an EC2 micro instance running with the Amazon linux. I installed bind and set up an entry for a certain domain, and it works fine if you are on that server and type:

nslookup the-domain.com localhost

but I can't get to it from external servers by typing

nslookup the-domain.com 10-10-10-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com

In my security group, I set it to allow incoming traffic on port 53 (both TCP and UDP) but still, nothing. Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: System administration questions should be asked at http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line in your named.conf global options. "any" in these refer to any IP address, you could restrict access to specific clients by listing those IP addresses -

```
listen-on { any; };
```

For IPv6:

```
listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
```

The zones may also have restrictions placed using

```
allow-query { i.p.ad.rr; }
```